# C# Get Value of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I got a problem with 2 DataGrid Views. Both are the same. the only different is, that the second one has a filter to sort out the closed cases.

**So there are:**
faelleDataGridView
faelleDataGridView2

All I want is to select the value of the column "ID" of the selected row. After that it will open a new form were I set the varaible for the new filter (I only want to see entries whitch fit to the ID).

This will start after i have made a double click on the cell.

This is my source code:

```
        private void faelleDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    { // This one is working with no errors

        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            FallDetail fFallDetail = new FallDetail();
            DataGridViewRow row = faelleDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            //MessageBox.Show(row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
            fFallDetail.fFilter = row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
            fFallDetail.Show();
        }

    }

    private void faelleDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    { // This one will result an error
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            FallDetail fFallDetail = new FallDetail();
            DataGridViewRow row = faelleDataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            //MessageBox.Show(row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
            fFallDetail.fFilter = row.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
            fFallDetail.Show();
        }
    }
```

After I have started the second one I got an error. It says, that he can not find the cell named "ID".

The Error (translated from german): An exception error of the type "System.ArgumentException" is occurred at System.Windows.Forms.dll.

Additional Information: The column ID could not be found.

I have checked The ID column is only visible=false. But there is the same at the first datagridview.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem or what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**Fixed the Problem by using the correct name in the properties**

Greez Rok

Comment: Can you make the column visible=true in the second grid and test once, if that is causing the problem? Also tag the question as Winform or wpf or asp. Whichever is applicable

Comment: Hey thanks for youre answer. The problem stays if I set visible=true. Strange is, that only the first datagridview is working. If I make copies they're not working.

Comment: Sorry I was just making sure...One short comment, you need not have different methods, you can use the same method for both the grids. You just need to use `var gridview = sender as DataGrid` and then use it going forward.

Comment: Whats the index number of the column of the column you are trying to access? It might work with the index number rather than the key.

Comment: Hey Thanks so I have to enter the same method to the event handler? Did I understand it correct? So the Method only is working like this: private void AnyDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) { //code here }

Comment: The Index number is 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search for index `fFallDetail.fFilter = row.Cells ["ID"]. Value.ToString ();` which is put the name of the column, check that each column is the appropriate name. One thing is the header and another thing is the name. You can check it from the properties in the GridView designer.

Comment: Hey thanks :) but the Headername and the DataPropertyName is absolutly the same :/

Comment: Ah I got what u mean I guess that was my fault :D

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm glad I helped. Greetings!